# How to format the TSV file in Druid

Tags: json, hadoop, druid

I am trying to load in a TSV in druid using this ingestion speck:

**MOST UPDATED SPEC BELOW:**

```
{                                                                                                                                                                                               
"type" : "index",
"spec" : {
    "ioConfig" : {
        "type" : "index",
        "inputSpec" : {
            "type": "local",
            "baseDir": "quickstart",
            "filter": "test_data.json"
        }
    },
    "dataSchema" : {
        "dataSource" : "local",
        "granularitySpec" : {
            "type" : "uniform",
            "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
            "queryGranularity" : "none",
            "intervals" : ["2016-07-18/2016-07-22"]
        },
        "parser" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "parseSpec" : {
                "format" : "json",
                "dimensionsSpec" : {
                    "dimensions" : ["name", "email", "age"]
                },
                "timestampSpec" : {
                    "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                     "column" : "date"
                }
            }
        },
        "metricsSpec" : [
            {
                "name" : "count",
                "type" : "count"
            },
            {
              "type" : "doubleSum",
              "name" : "age",
              "fieldName" : "age"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

**If my schema looks like this:**

```
Schema: name    email    age
```

**And actual dataset looks like this:**

```
name    email    age    Bob    Jones    23    Billy    Jones    45
```

Is this how the columns should be formatted^^ in the above dataset for a TSV? Like `name    email    age` should be first (the columns) and then the actual data. I am confused how Druid will know how to map the columns to the actual dataset in TSV format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TSV stands for tab separated format, so it looks the same as csv but you will use tabs instead of commas e.g.

```
Name<TAB>Age<TAB>Address
Paul<TAB>23<TAB>1115 W Franklin
Bessy the Cow<TAB>5<TAB>Big Farm Way
Zeke<TAB>45<TAB>W Main St
```

you will use frist line as header to define your column names - so you can use "name", "age" or "email" in dimensions in your spec file

as for the gmt and utc, they are basically the same

> There is no time difference between Greenwich Mean Time and
>   Coordinated Universal Time

first one is time zone, the other one is a time standard

btw don`t forget to include a column with some time value in your tsv file!!

so e.g. if you will have tsv file that looks like:

```
"name"  "position"  "office"    "age"   "start_date"    "salary"
"Airi Satou"    "Accountant"    "Tokyo" "33"    "2016-07-16T19:20:30+01:00" "162700"
"Angelica Ramos"    "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)" "London"    "47"    "2016-07-16T19:20:30+01:00" "1200000"
```

your spec file should look like this:

```
{
    "spec" : {
        "ioConfig" : {
            "inputSpec" : {
                "type": "local",
                "baseDir": "path_to_folder",
                "filter": "name_of_the_file(s)"
            }
        },
        "dataSchema" : {
            "dataSource" : "local",
            "granularitySpec" : {
                "type" : "uniform",
                "segmentGranularity" : "hour",
                "queryGranularity" : "none",
                "intervals" : ["2016-07-01/2016-07-28"]
            },
            "parser" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "parseSpec" : {
                    "format" : "tsv",
                    "dimensionsSpec" : {
                        "dimensions" : [
                            "position",
                            "age",
                            "office"
                        ]
                    },
                    "timestampSpec" : {
                        "format" : "auto",
                         "column" : "start_date"
                    }
                }
            },
            "metricsSpec" : [
                {
                    "name" : "count",
                    "type" : "count"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "sum_sallary",
                    "type" : "longSum",
                    "fieldName" : "salary"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```